# How do I add data to a list of objects?

Tags: python, list, object

#I know there's an easier approach to this problem but right now I have a list of objects and a list of data that needs to be added to each object individually. My code looks like this:

```
data=[1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,6.5]
class Person(object):
  def __init__(self,name):
    self.name=name
   self.data=0.0

Aiden=Person("Aiden")
AidenTwo=Person("AidenTwo")
AidenThree=Person("AidenThree")
AidenFour=Person("AidenFour")
AidenFive=Person("AidenFive")
AidenSix=Person("AidenSix")
AidenSeven=Person("AidenSeven")
AidenEight=Person("AidenEight")
AidenNine=Person("AidenNine")
AidenTen=Person("AidenTen")

list_of_people=[]
list_of_people.append(Aiden)
list_of_people.append(AidenTwo)
list_of_people.append(AidenThree)
list_of_people.append(AidenFour)
list_of_people.append(AidenFive)
list_of_people.append(AidenSix)
list_of_people.append(AidenSeven)
list_of_people.append(AidenEight)
list_of_people.append(AidenNine)
list_of_people.append(AidenTen)



for p in range(0,len(list_of_people)):
  Person.data=data[p]
#This line/ for loop right here is the problem.
```

Comment: `list_of_people = [Aiden, AidenTwo, AidenThree, ...]`?

Comment: Can you show the implementation of the `Person` Class?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
for p, d in zip(list_of_people, data):
  p.data = d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can zip-and-assign the data to the people like this:

```
for person, person.data in zip(list_of_people, data):
    pass
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZNfa8MgFMXf/RTSlyYgoVvXUQZ52MP2OAbrWykha25WR6ZibPen9LNnXmtCzIMKCTm/c696MOrXHKRYrpXuuqo0Zb69Ybdsye7Yys17nNlqR8i@KduWvoJupUjk@yfsTfpAqB0V1LQouOCmKJIWmpqJ8gs8xIFahlqOj1B2iy6yxahTa7RvNOqhwRy1oPXc7@A8NL0weh5aXdI5IY@8ApF748x9zdKruvmWIbDCwA4aYEJR6vmzPOoQozJQfpoUo9LTN/4TQisMDE7T7Tqp50/842BC7qSev3AxWRmV4VTT3hvXmTS8NYWsCwVSNZBvdxMlK5UCUSWuJo1BG2GcY4hRB@YYN9goowYbZ5xjoFGHizTqwFTjB8UlCKmlpsolzvzbXU3KBf3jKgkbMIrMX3Rlf7FxPZaEdu/TXJjk6km77h8) (see the "Output" section where I print the updated people, supported by an added `__str__` method)